# Carnap's Logical Syntax of Language

Tags: philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy, philosophy-of-language

I don't quite understand the objective of his paper on the matter of scientific language and the application of his languages I II and corresponding syntax. I also don't understand why his and Vienna Circle's metaphysical stance was so important and necessary - it seems rather trivial and worthless. I believe a bit of the history and problems of his time would help further my comprehension.

Comment: See here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/carnap/
here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/carnap/syntax.html
and here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/vienna-circle/

Comment: Carnap's project is not today very "alive and well"... Originally, starting from the impressive development of 20th Century math logic and axiomatic mathematic, Carnap aimed at develop formally ALL scientific languages and theories. See Pierre Wagner (editor), [Carnap's Logical Syntax of Language (Palgrave, 2009)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Carnap_s_Logical_Syntax_of_Language/EqcYDAAAQBAJ)

Comment: The gist of Carnap's paper on the matter of scientific language is to separate synthetic factual observational terms and theoretical mathematical terms of sentences of a scientific theory TC into Ramsey sentences RTC such that RTC must be logically equivalent to TC. In RTC the synthetic/analytic distinction is required to be thoroughly clear in such a way that without any mathematical or metaphysical knowledge laypeople can easily verify the factual observational sentences of any scientific theory, which is obviously extremely hard to achieve in practice though it may be possible in theory...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the response.

Comment: @DoubleKnot Thanks for the response.

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: I found Carnap's Logical Syntax of Language by Pierre Wagner to be incredibly helpful and inciteful to the matters talked above.